# The simplest way of running a cross-compiled executable in a FreeBSD environment

Tags: docker, freebsd, compile, cross-platform

I have an executable cross-compiled for FreeBSD in a docker container.

What is the simplest way of running it?

Comment: It should run in any FreeBSD VM. What was your intention in compiling the application for FreeBSD?

Comment: I am developing a Rust sysinfo implementation for FreeBSD. Is it possible to put my app inside a FreeBSD *.iso so I may run it directly from the installation media?

Comment: I don't know if the installation disc gives an environment where applications can be run manually. If not, you'll need to complete the installation to create a working VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern FreeBSD installation ISOs do indeed permit live use of FreeBSD's CLI.  Copying the executable into a custom-burned ISO may not be the easiest route, though.  Slightly easier, assuming you have both a burned ISO and a spare thumb drive, is to put the executable on the thumb drive, boot the ISO, mount the thumbdrive, and run the executable from the thumbdrive.

Actually, if you have a spare thumbdrive, then it's probably just as easy and somewhat faster to skip the optical media.  Download a "memstick" installation image and `dd` the image to the thumbdrive as directed in section 2.3.1.1 of the handbook:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-pre.html

After you've dd'ed the image onto the thumbdrive, mount the thumbdrive and copy your executable into `/mnt/root` or someplace of your own choosing.  Now boot the thumbdrive, and you can run your executable from the directory you placed it into.